# How can I automatically get the latest version of the Browser?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, linux, update

[The package for Arch Linux](https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/PKGBUILD?h=tor-browser-hardened) currently depends on someone manually changing the `$pkgver` variable every time the package is updated upstream. Is there a link that always redirects to the latest version of the package or a better way to detect what the current version is? I am aware that the releases are found [here](https://dist.torproject.org/torbrowser/), but that doesn't have a static folder for the latest build.

Comment: Here is a quote from Launchpad : "You can update your system with unsupported packages from this untrusted PPA by adding **ppa:webupd8team/tor-browser** to your system's Software Sources." sources : https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/tor-browser

Comment: @wo4v51v5774sdk9j Arch doesn't use PPAs.

Comment: https://gettor.torproject.org/api/latest.json but pkgver must be defined before the source fetch happens. So I don't think this would help, the update wouldn't happen without manual intervention still.

Comment: @canonizingironize Actually you could probably get the current version from [HERE](https://gettor.torproject.org/api/latest/stable/linux/en-US.json) with some grep magic.

Comment: I think the problem is in the PKGBUILD file config though? how does it know theres a new version to build if it needs to run the build script to find out if theres a new version?

Comment: The  packages are manually built by the user anyway. This way, the user always gets the latest version as of when the script was run. Sort of like -git packages, which retrieve the latest source through git.

Answer (score 1):

The AUR package should stay pretty up to date. If you want to help keep it up, you can subscribe to one of the places that new releases are announced (I use the blog rss feed) and flag the package when a new release comes out.

By default, TBB will notify you on startup if your version is out of date. I have not checked the Arch version, but on my Mac I can use the built-in updater to download and install any updates.

Comment: the built-in updater will not work on a system install, since it would require root permissions, and no one should be running tor browser as root.

Comment: Ah, good point - I forgot that on OS X my homebrew caskroom is owned by my (unprivileged) user.